# Making line thickness scale proportional to zoom in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geomedia

I'd like to ask how I can see my outline at the same size independent of my zoom level. I've used GeoMedia in the past where you can set the final scale of your map first (let's say 1:5000) and then define the line thickness (let's say 3pt). The thing is that there is an option to draw the line thicker if I zoom in the data view. For example, if I am in the Data View and zoomed to 1:2500, my line will be 6pt thick.

This doesn't affect anything in the final map, but the line will be thicker, which is very nice for looking if features intersect each other and it's easier the line thickness directly instead of going back and forth between the final map scale and the scale I am working on (usually much more zoomed in).

TLDR: How can I configure ArcGis 10 so that my line thickness is proportional to the scale in the Data View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is called "reference scale" in ArcGIS.

Right click on your dataframe after setting the scale that you want for reference, then go to "reference scale > set reference scale" in the context menu.

There is a [video](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/tutorials/Editor_Ex10_2.htm) if you like to visalize